# Почему скрипт на LogOn в домене у пользователя с административными правами запускается с повышением прав?

Tags: windows

Имеется домашний домен. При входе у пользователя запускается скрипт, который подключает домашнюю папку на сервере. Долго мучился не понимая почему у меня не подключается диск. Думал не отрабатывает скрипт. В итоге разобрался, скрипт запускается с повышением прав до администратора, поэтому подключенный диск виден только администратору. Если этот скрипт просто запустить после входа в домен, то этот же диск подключается у меня как у обычного пользователя и виден в проводнике.
Поиски в интернете показывают, что всех интересует вопрос как повысить права, а мне вот надо понизить... ;)

Comment: А почему это не сделать штатными средствами `GPO`?

Comment: А почему бы не раскрыть секрет как? Забыл упомянуть, что скрипт на .vbs

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос вроде бы решился. Вывод - не стоит мапить диски скриптами. Для этого действительно есть специальный механизм в GPO:

> Конфигурация пользователя -> Настройка -> Конфигурация Windows -> Сопоставление дисков

Добавляем нужный диск, в пути указываем что-то типа `\\SRV\Users\%USERNAME%`

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать `/trustlevel` ключ для команды `runas`. Пример:

**CheckAdmin.ps1** (скрипт просто отображает, юзер админ или нет):

```
$adminRole = [Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator
$principal = [Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
$isAdmin = $principal.IsInRole($adminRole)
Write-Host "IsAdmin=$isAdmin"
pause
```

Запускаю с консоли от администратора:

```
PS C:\> .\CheckAdmin.ps1
IsAdmin=True
Press Enter to continue...:
PS C:\> runas.exe /trustlevel:0x20000 "powershell.exe -File CheckAdmin.ps1"
```

В появившемся окошке отображается:

```
IsAdmin=False
Press Enter to continue...:
```

Comment: Интересное предложение, но я не силён в power shell. Скрипт выдран из интернет на .vbs и делать отдельный скрипт на запуск скрипта как-то не хочется...

Comment: @EwgenJanch суть не в павершеле, вам нужна только runas команда

Comment: Для экспериментов добавил в скрипт две строки WshShell.Run "cmd.exe"
WshShell.Run "runas.exe /trustlevel:0x20000 cmd.exe"
Открываются два окна, у первого в заголовке "Администратор: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe", а у второго "Администратор: cmd.exe (запущено от имени DOMAIN\User с ограниченными правами". В обоих есть доступ к подключенному в этом же скрипте сетевому диску, а в системе - нету... :( так что этот метод не рабочий. Или я опять что-то не так сделал...

Comment: @EwgenJanch наверное проблема в другом, ведь вы видите в окошке, что оно с ограниченными правами